# Outlook Mobile Add-in manifest sample?

Tags: mobile, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I was trying to add in the mobile part for the Outlook Add-in.

I have search the information in https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/add-mobile-support for the manifest to update for mobile.

However, for that, I am getting the following issue in return when trying to install from the Manage Add-in.

```
This app can't be installed. 
The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'VersionOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'. 
List of possible elements expected: 'DisableEntityHighlighting' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' as well as 'VersionOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides' as well as any element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'...
```

Since it does not really show us the manifest part for the OfficeApp tag or any other parts.
I wonder if there is any sample which shows the whole manifest for the mobile; I could only find the one for the Desktop.

I tried just update the VersionOverrides to newer version

`<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">`

and it failed too.

Is it even complete yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I tried just update the VersionOverrides to newer version

This is not what documentation says to do. I quote: "The MobileFormFactor element is defined in the VersionOverrides v1.1 schema, so you will need to include a VersionOverrides element both for v1.0 and v1.1." Please have a look on [command-demo-manifest.xml](https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo/blob/master/command-demo-manifest.xml) eample.

Comment: Thanks, it does help, however, the v1.1 VersionOverrides needs to be in the v1.0 VersionOverrides, which is the part I missed.